# How to group multiple buttons together so, that only one can stay focussed?

Tags: java, android

[Please click here to see the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1b1P5.png)This is a screen of a blood bank, I am developing but I am stuck at implementing the choose blood group option. Should I use them as buttons or text views? Also I want only one option to be selected, since a person cant have more than 1 type of blood group. Also the option selected must move on to the next activity.

Comment: Perhaps radio buttons are what you're looking for?

Comment: use `choice chip` as its a better option than radio button, [official docs](https://material.io/components/chips#choice-chips) are good place to start from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's two way to do it.

1. Chip Group
2. Radio Button.

Here I am implementing source code of Chip group.

```
<com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

       

          <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
                android:id="@+id/chip4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:text="Text"/>
</com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup>
```

You have to add more chip. Only single chip can be selected at once. If you want to enable multiple chip. Than, you have to remove ChipGroup or, create more ChipGroup.To do like that picture you have to change colors.

RadioGroup :

```
<RadioGroup
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioButton"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="RadioButton" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="RadioButton" />
</RadioGroup>
```

Radio Button works like that but, radioButton design isn't like as you shown.

Answer (score 0):

Use [MaterialButtonToogleGroup](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/button/MaterialButtonToggleGroup) from Material Components. Inside it use MaterialButton for choices. For more information please refer to this [link](https://material.io/components/buttons/#toggle-button)